# Trane HVAC in horizontal position - why does evaporator throw condensation?

Tags: hvac, condensation, evaporative-cooling

I appreciate assistance from anyone who has had or understands the problem. 
 I have a Trane HVAC system in a horizontal "left" flow configuration in the attic.  Ambient temperature is about 95 degrees when it's running in summer (which is now).  The unit is brand new this year, and cools amazingly.  The only issue is condensation.  I have verified that the actual PVC line (pictured) is clear and is dripping water outside (this part of Texas is very humid).

However, the bottom board in the outlet plenum is soaked and heavy with water.

Another possible clue, note the configuration of the PVC drain with the "vent" on the top.  When this is open it blows cold air out and I'm thinking that can't be right, so I've put a "cap" on it.  Surely it's not correct to have cold air blowing out of that.

Am I missing something in the configuration which should be catching the condensation?  Thanks

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]
[image: picture 3]
[image: picture 4]
[image: picture 5]
[image: picture 6]